# inserting record in parent child table in single transaction But When send more then one object i Gives error instance ! instance cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I get this exception:

> The instance of entity type 'CameraActivity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ActivityId', 'FeatureId', 'CamId'} is already being tracked.
>
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
>
> Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."}

This is my Post method

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Camera>> PostCamera(Camera camera)
{
    var cameraRecodExists = _context.Cameras.FirstOrDefault(C => C.IPAdress == camera.IPAdress) ;

    if (cameraRecodExists !=null)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "Record Already Exists" });
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Cameras.Add(camera);

        // _context.SaveChanges();
        foreach (var activity in camera.CameraActivities)
        {
            activity.CamId = camera.CamId;
            activity.ActivityId = camera.CameraActivities.First().ActivityId;
            activity.FeatureId = camera.CameraActivities.First().FeatureId;
        }

        _context.CameraActivities.AddRange(camera.CameraActivities);

        try 
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var a = ex;
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCamera", new { id = camera.CamId }, camera);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) and try to save `camera` along with `camera.CameraActivities`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Camera>> PostCamera(Camera camera)
{
    var cameraRecodExists = _context.Cameras.FirstOrDefault(C => C.IPAdress == camera.IPAdress) ;

    if (cameraRecodExists !=null)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "Record Already Exists" });
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Cameras.Add(camera); 
        try 
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var a = ex;
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCamera", new { id = camera.CamId }, camera);
    }
}
```